# Is the function in namespace code running into infinite loop or what?

Tags: php, function, namespaces, global, built-in

I'm using **PHP 7.2.1**

Consider below code :

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;

const E_ERROR = 45;
function strlen($str)
{
    return strlen($str) - 1;
}

echo E_ERROR, "\n"; // prints "45"
echo INI_ALL, "\n"; // prints "7" - falls back to global INI_ALL

echo strlen('hi'), "\n"; // prints "1"
if (is_array('hi')) { // prints "is not array"
    echo "is array\n";
} else {
    echo "is not array\n";
}
?>
```

**Output :**

```
45 
7 

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ... on line 7
```

As per my knowledge, PHP will fall back to global function if a namespaced function does not exist.

Then why I am getting **Fatal error** here?

Also, is the fatal error I've received mean that the program is running into infinite loop? If yes, how? If no, what's the exact meaning of this fatal error?

Comment: All I see is that the "namespaced" function exists...

Comment: *"fall back to global function if a namespaced function does not exist"* – well, but `strlen` *does* exist in your namespace, and it's an infinite recursive function. Of course the only thing it can do is run out of memory.

Comment: same as: `function myfunc($num)
{
    return myfunc($num) - 1;
}` use `return \strlen($str) - 1;` to have it call the PHP built-in.

Comment: @deceze I mean, honestly I would have expected it to overrun some sort of vertically oriented memory structure... :3c

Comment: @Sammitch Ah, like a *silo exhaust*? Yeah, same difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code you are using does run in an infinite loop. Here's how my test results look (a little more informative):

```
~ » php test.php
45
7
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, 
aborting! in /Users/xxx/test.php on line 5
```

If you are already overwriting std php function (which I would not recommend), you have to then explicitly run the std function by prefixing it with the backslash (use the global namespace).

```
<?php
namespace A\B\C;

const E_ERROR = 45;
function strlen($str)
{
    return \strlen($str) - 1;
}

echo E_ERROR, "\n"; // prints "45"
echo INI_ALL, "\n"; // prints "7" - falls back to global INI_ALL

echo strlen('hi'), "\n"; // prints "1"
if (is_array('hi')) { // prints "is not array"
    echo "is array\n";
} else {
    echo "is not array\n";
}
```

Results:

```
~ » php test.php
45
7
1
is not array
```

EDIT: Only now I've found this manual with a very similar example: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php